# The meaning of "make it into"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Explain me please the meaning of the phrase in next context:

> Bleeding edge technology is a category of technologies so new that they could have a high risk of being unreliable and lead adopters to incur greater expense in order to make use of them. By its nature, a proportion of bleeding edge technology will make it into the mainstream. For example, email was once considered to be bleeding edge.

Source: Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleeding_edge_technology).

What is **it** in the sentence *By its nature, a proportion of...?* I'm confused because of the general meaning of phrase *make smth into smth* is

> to change something into something else

Source: [Cambridge Dictionaries Online](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/make-sth-into-sth)

So that as I think, in the  *By its nature...* sentence, the **bleeding edge technology** is a subject, **it** is an object, and subject will change object (what exactly?) into mainstream. Or **make it into** is just an idiomatic construction with the meaning "become" or ''come into (use)" ? Can I then say "A proportion of bleeding edge technology **will be made** into the mainstream."?

Answer (score 2):

"Make it into" means "make its way into."

For example, if you were waiting at the end of a very long line of people to get into a concert, I might ask you the next day: "Did you make it into the concert?"

Similarly, if you are trying to get to the post office before it closes, you might say, "I'm afraid I'm not going to make it."

So you've looked up the wrong definition.  You're not making *something* into something, you're *making it* into something.

Applying this to your text, we could rewrite the sentence thus:

> By its nature, a proportion of bleeding edge technology will be incorporated into the mainstream.

Or even:

> By its nature, a proportion of bleeding edge technology will become mainstream.

This latter rewrite, however, does change the sense somewhat, in particular, the focus.

Edit: There is persistent insistence that "make something into something" means to transform.  However, that is not the correct sense for this use of the phrase "make it into."

Rather, it is the preposition "into" with the phrasal verb "make it," meaning to reach or attain.  It is not necessary to use an additional preposition, but it is possible.  For example, you can ask someone, *did you make it?*

One can *make it over the bridge;* one can *make it to the church in time;* one can *make it under the limbo bar.*  And an idea can *make it into* a document.

Here's a sample of what Google returned for an exact phrase search on *"make it into."*  I am ignoring the hit for this question itself, for one irrelevant result, and I'm only counting the first instance of Meryl Streep's Golden Globes speech; otherwise these are the results that appeared on the first two pages.  I evaluate each result as to whether it represents the meaning "transform" or "attain inclusion."

- Meryl Streep quoting Carrie Fisher saying "take your broken heart, make it into art"

Transform

- 6 CRAZY HERO ABILITIES That Didn't Make It Into Overwatch - YouTube

Attain inclusion

- Is it too late for me to make it into Yale? - Quora

Attain inclusion

- The Next Craft Beer Trend: Make It Into Whiskey - Men's Journal

Transform

- ROGUE ONE Trailer Moments That Didn't Make It Into The Film | Birth ...

Attain inclusion

- New IRS data show that 71% of US taxpayers who make it into the ‘Top 400’ are there for only a single year

Attain inclusion

- Lost Scriptures: Books that Did Not Make It into the New Testament ...

Attain inclusion

- Make it into management. african-female. The corporate sector can be highly competitive. If you have been working hard and not getting the promotion you feel

Attain inclusion

- Ideas on Photography - make it into a game.

Transform

- Do Stokes, Broad & Cook make it into your top 10 of 2016? - BBC Sport

Attain inclusion

- Which Star Wars Trailer Moments Didn't Make It Into The Movie

Attain inclusion

- Can Georgia make it into the top five of recruiting classes? - ESPN Video

Attain inclusion

- 5 Facts About McDonald's That Didn't Make It Into 'The Founder' - Peta

Attain inclusion

- How can longshot teams make it into the playoffs? - NFL Videos

Attain inclusion

- Packers will pound the Lions, Redskins make it into the playoffs.

Attain inclusion

That's three points for "transform" and twelve points for "attain inclusion."

Comment: It would be helpful if people who downvote would explain.

Comment: did you make it to the concert, not into as far as I know, make into is more like transform

Comment: @KalpeshSoni a person goes *to* a concert, but *into* a building. So you can say "he was unable to make his way into the stadium because the crowds were too thick."  Similarly, an idea can make its way into a discussion.

Comment: you are explaining me difference between to and into, and I am saying difference between make to and make into - for example put on, put off and put up with have nothing to do with on off and with http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-sth-into-sth

Comment: @KalpeshSoni the fact remains that "make it into" doesn't necessarily mean transform.  In some cases, it is simply the preposition "into" with the verb "make it," meaning to reach or to attain.  See definition 19 at https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make.  This verb can be used with many prepositions: make it to the concert, make it over the wall, make it under the limbo bar, make it into the document.  I will edit the answer to clarify.

Comment: so then an idea made into this story will mean completely different things to you and me. To me the idea was the story

Comment: @KalpeshSoni consider the phrase "the team made it into the top 10": it does not mean that the team *became* the top 10; rather, it means that the team *achieved membership* in the top 10.  Similarly, if an idea makes it into the story, the idea achieves inclusion in the story.  See the Star Wars trailer quote for an example.